# How use library at linux driver use linux source code tree to compile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-device-driver, kbuild

I want to modify the wifi driver of Linux, because I want use `ioctl` and `socket` to change the channel. So first I use a library to implement those function and install it to linux with the header file in /usr/local/include/ folder.
For normal program, if I want to use this library all I need to do is add `-llibaryname` in the compile command.
But since the driver uses Linux source code, it uses its own Makefile and uses the rule call `Kbuild`.
I want to know how to modify the Makefile to let me use the library?
Or is there are other way to reach my goal?

Comment: There are different sets of `CFLAGS` used in Kbuild Makefile(s). `EXTRA_CFLAGS` seems like perhaps a good option for what you are looking for.